# unknown IP address

Tags: networking

I have an instrument on a local network (XP computer and instrument via a crossover cable) with an unknown IP address, how can I find the address of the instrument?
I inherited an old instrument with an Ethernet interface.  I have contacted the manufacture and asked for help in determining the IP address of the instrument.  The manufacture doesn’t support the instrument, but they were able to give me the default IP address.   The instrument is not responding to the default address.  It seems the previous owner has change the default address and I need to find the current IP address before communicating with the instrument.
When scanning for the IP address, is there a way of scanning a range of IP addresses larger than the subnet?  How should I setup the Mask and Gateway on the computer to maximize the number of IP addresses to be scanned?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/480183/trying-to-find-ip-of-a-directly-connected-device

Comment: Does if have a console port?  If so, I'd just connect to it via serial and a console client like PuTTY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been there and done that.

It's not that difficult.

First: 
Hook the device up on a regular LAN with DHCP and see if it tries to obtain an ip-address that way.
If it does, problem solved.

Second:
Set the XP computer to an arbitrary address/subnet.
192.168.1.1./255.255.255.0 will do just fine.
Install Wireshark on the XP computer and let it listen to all traffic.

Then do a ping 255.255.255.255 from a Command Prompt window.

You should see some response from the device in Wireshark from which you can get the ip-address.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I will give your suggestion a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try is running tcpdump or something similar and plugging the device in.

Comment: The instrument is setup for a static address.  The computer is not the original computer running the instrument.

Comment: It's likely that the device will broadcast when connected. See @nedm's response for details.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) on the XP system and start a capture -- make sure your LAN connection is set to collect packets promiscuously in the Wireshark configuration first.

Connect to the device and do watch the capture to see what address it's showing for ARP requests and any other attempts to communicate.

Note that you may not need a crossover cable depending on what type of device it is (and the type of ethernet controller on both it and your XP box).

Comment: Good thought about the cross-over cable. It might have an internal cross-over if it was intended to be used in a direct-connect setup with a PC.